# Spring (Boot): what's the difference between reaching EOL and no more OSS support?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The [Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions) differentiates between actively supported versions, versions that are "not actively supported anymore", and versions that reached end-of-life (EOL). Indeed for the 5.0 & 5.1 line, there have been no more releases after the announced "no--more-support" date of December 2020.
So what's the difference between "no active support" and EOL? Will e.g. libraries be updated if there's a CVE?

Similarly, [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions) differentiates between EOL & end of OSS support. While it claims that e.g. the 2.2.x line has OSS support until October 2020 and reaches EOL July 2021, releases have been made until January 2021, but none after that.
So what exactly happens in the time after OSS support has ended and EOL is reached? What can one expect here?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the main difference is.

OSS = Open source support - eg. you get support through github issues until that date.

EOL = End of life - even if you bought a subscription for commercial support through [VMware](https://tanzu.vmware.com/spring-runtime) (which is the company behind spring) for spring, you wont get any more support for this version after that date. So no security fixes or patches wont be delivered anymore.

So EOL is more critically and even important for business which bought commercial support for longer use of that particular version, whereas OSS end is relevant for most of the users.

You already linked the relevant parts - [Spring Boot Support Policy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions#spring-boot-support-policy)

> Commercial support is also available from VMware which offers an extended support period.

in contrast to

> Spring Boot releases are marked as "end of life" when they are no longer supported or released in any form.

To answer your question for what you can expect after end of OSS. You most likekly still get security issues fixed but no support (except maybe commercial support) when you run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

Both uses the same concept. EOL means that you will not get any patches, help or anything in any form for those versions.

End of OSS support and "no--more-support" means that you would get security patches as well as "severe" bugs up to EOL date.

In my experience, there has been some security updates for the versions between "end-of-support" and EOL but I do not recall a patch for a bug in any.

So, what it means is that, EOL versions in production should definitively be upgraded but you can wait a but for end-of-support. But, I would always recommend upgrading at a faster pace than that. If I do not need/want the newer features, I usually wait for x.x.1 but upgrade at that point - Spring Boot might be a little longer if you have dependencies that take some time to be compatible. i.e. Tanzu Application Service is still not updated for Spring Boot 2.5 - easiest way to check it out is through start.spring.io

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Do you have any sources for that or what's the base for your assessment?

Comment: Basically the links you provided is the only source I know about but was at a conference where it was explained.